# Java Punycode String

Tags: java, bouncycastle, punycode

I want to punycode a String in order to generate a csr using bouncycastle. Here I need the byte representation of the domain name. E.g

```
new GeneralName(GeneralName.dNSName, new DEROctetString(bytes..))
```

My question is: How do I encode [www..tld](http://www.xn--n28h.tld) correctly. I assumed that I could use `IDN.toASCII(domain).getBytes()`. Unfortunately this fails with:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: An unassigned code point was found in the input ?
    at java.base/sun.net.idn.StringPrep.map(StringPrep.java:303)
    at java.base/sun.net.idn.StringPrep.prepare(StringPrep.java:426)
    at java.base/java.net.IDN.toASCIIInternal(IDN.java:272)
```

Comment: Is that URL correct? I've never seen one with an emoji in it

Comment: Yes, Took the Exempel from https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji-Domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `IDN.ALLOW_UNASSIGNED` flag:

```java
IDN.toASCII("www..tld", IDN.ALLOW_UNASSIGNED)
```